# combine same the same datas into single field in a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table of colors. I want to combine the same colors into single field & also their sum of quantity will be shown in that row.

For example, In the table below I have 2 "black" colors with quantities 5 & 2. Now want to combine this 2 rows into one & the quantity field will be "5+2 = 7" .

what I want is---

```css
th{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Qty</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>white</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Black</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>red</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish it by a single pass using js [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) so need need to use multiple loops.

```js
const data = { colors: [{ "selectedColor": "white", "selectedQty": 0, "selectedUnit": "1", }, { "selectedColor": "black", "selectedQty": "2", "selectedUnit": "3", }, { "selectedColor": "black", "selectedQty": 5, "selectedUnit": "2", }, { "selectedColor": "red", "selectedQty": 0, "selectedUnit": "6", } ]};

const result = data.colors.reduce((acc, {
  selectedColor: sc,
  selectedQty: sq,
  selectedUnit: su
}) => {

  if (acc[sc]) return {
    ...acc,
    [sc]: {
      selectedColor: sc,
      selectedQty: acc[sc].selectedQty + parseInt(sq),
      selectedUnit: acc[sc].selectedUnit + parseInt(su)
    }
  }

  return {
    ...acc,
    [sc]: {
      selectedColor: sc,
      selectedQty: parseInt(sq),
      selectedUnit: parseInt(su)
    }
  }

}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: "The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range." --- it's showing this. But when I refresh the page it shows correctly

Comment: I don't want to change the "selectedUnit" field. This will remain as it is

Comment: @16_018_RHR So you don't want to add values of `selectedUnit`, right?

Comment: yeah. actually I want to add another field called "rate" which will be multiplied with quantity. i did that but when I change the selectedColor, the rate field disappears

Answer (score 2):

You should create a computed method to create a new array, Instead of calling the data in your `v-for` you can call the computed.

I did that in a codepen :
https://codepen.io/ValentinM27/pen/GRGvmMp?editors=1011

Here is the main part of the code :

```js
...
computed: {
      getGrouped() {
        let groupedColor = [];
        this.colors.forEach((c, index) => {
          // We check if the color has already been handle
          const alreadyExist = groupedColor.some(existC => existC.selectedColor === c.selectedColor);
          
          // If yes, we don't handle it again
          if(alreadyExist) return;
          
          this.colors.forEach((c2, index2) => {
            // If it is the same color but not the actual index, we do the traitement
            if(c.selectedColor === c2.selectedColor && index !== index2) {
              c.selectedQty = parseInt(c.selectedQty) + parseInt(c2.selectedQty);
              c.selectedUnit = parseInt(c.selectedUnit) + parseInt(c2.selectedUnit);
            }
          })
          
          // We push the concatened color value
          groupedColor.push(c);
        })
        
        // Our array with concatened values
        return groupedColor;
      }
   },
...
```

And in your template

```
...
<tbody v-for="(color, i) in getGrouped" :key="i">
...
```

Hope it is what you are looking for

Comment: In your example the the qty and rate are not summed up, but appended because in OPs example they are integers and strings mixed. So probably best to convert them to integers before they are summed up

Comment: Yes sure, but I though that was a mistake to put strings here

Comment: I corrected it : )